# Video Streaming is slow with OpenCV

Tags: performance, opencv, frame, webcam

I'm doing video processing application using C++ with OpenCV. This is how I have written coding to initialize web cam.

```
    storage = cvCreateMemStorage( 0 );
capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(1);

cvNamedWindow( "video", 1 );

while( key != 'q' ) {
    frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
    if( !frame ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Cannot query frame!\n" );
        break;
    }
    cvFlip( frame, frame, 1 );
    frame->origin = 0;
    key = cvWaitKey( 1 );
}
```

Can anyone suggest me a solution in order to increase the speed of capturing frames from web cam. There is like 3 seconds delay when compare to actual web cam video stream with OpenCV application web cam video stream.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What version of opencv are you using? Are you using the build that uses Intel Threading Building Blocks (tbb.dll)? If not, then use it, that is your speed-up right there.

You can also try a bare-bones code just to see what type of speed up you get:

storage = cvCreateMemStorage( 0 );
capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(1);

while (1) {
 frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
 cvWaitKey(1);
 }

Other than that, I suggest using the c++ interface to opencv, the c interface is quite ugly and might be slower.

Comment: hi
it's opencv 2.3 actually the speed problem comes when i try to detect objects in video only. Like I'm trying to detect user's face with,

CvSeq *faces = cvHaarDetectObjects(img, cascade, storage, 1.1, 3, 0, cvSize( 40, 40 ) );

this line of code make video speed low. Can I know what's wrong with it?

thank you

Comment: Hi again, was able to speed up the video stream by increasing the scale factor to 1.5 :)
thnx again for ur help